# Google maps mapsgl vector format or other map tile vector formats

Tags: google-maps, opengl, svg, vector-graphics, openstreetmap

I was wondering if anyone knew anything about the new Google maps mapsgl format for their vector data. I have worked some with open street maps data and rendering it to raster tiles with Mapnik. I noticed Mapnik can also render to svg file as vector data, but the uncompressed svg files are bigger then the raster images. After seeing the new mapgl thing from Google I was wondering what they did or anyone else for vector data that is chucked up in tiles. I would like to know of any other data formats that might be used for storing open street maps data in as vector data that can be rendered quickly. Seeing how Google maps mapgl is working in a web app I would be interested in any detail of how they did it.

My current focus would be rending the data with a desktop program using OpenGL, but it would be ideal if the formats could work on the web or mobile apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox made "Vector tiles" and that is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix up **geographic** vector data formats with SVG. SVG is intended purely for graphic rendering and its semantics doesn't know anything about the source geographic data. So SVG definitively not a good format to keep your geo data (and it's too verbose anyway).

What you would need is some kind of binary format (better suited for desktop apps) or very terse JSON (better for Web clients) to store OSM data in.

I suggest reading this QA: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/how-to-create-vector-polygons-at-the-same-amazing-speeds-giscloud-is-able-to-ren

There are also some attempts to formulate a binary OSM protocol, but I don't know what state these projects are in:

- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Binary_Format
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Mobile_Binary_Protocol